# drag and drop images from GalleryView widget

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, galleryview

I have a GalleryView widget in my application that displays over 100 images. I would like to add the drag and drop feature by which users can long press on any of the 100 images, and pull them down to a tray at the bottom of the display. I need directions to do this or any sample application or code which would help me get started.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Ab

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check out this example

https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView

Comment: That'll be a good start, but it doesn't feature a "tray" or dragging children between two parent views. Good luck!